# Limitation of String in android

Tags: java, android

Is there any limitation in string in android.
I am getting a response after an http request which is a much bigger string. 
My problem is that I am not getting the entire string. 
what may be the reason?
I am using this code

```
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); // response string
GlobalClass.printLine("Response >> " + responseBody);
```

Comment: if you use the LogCat , you will get all of your String displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is, but in my opinion it's more the Log file or your

```
GlobalClass.printLine("Response >> " + responseBody);
```

which has limitation. Can you try to save your String in a file ?